# unable to get the specname in cypress details.specName

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am creating a function in cypress that will take a screenshot on failure and put a custom filename on the screenshot and save it in a specific library.

`takess.ts`:

```
export function renameAndMoveScreenshot(details: any) {
let specName = ''; // Initialize specName variable

sendSpecNameToPlugin: (name:string) => specName = name;

Cypress.on('after:screenshot', () => {
const testname = (details.specName || specName).replace(/\.|\/|\s/g, '_');
const timeStamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '_');
const filename = `${testname}--${timeStamp} (failed).png`;
const path = '../../screenshots';
const newPath = `${path}/${filename}`;
console.log (newPath)

if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    console.log('creating directory')
  fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.rename(details.path, newPath, (err: any) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve({ path: newPath });
    }
  });
  });
});`
```

Cypress.config.ts

```
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {   
  on('task',  {
      sendSpecNameToPlugin: (name) => specName = name
      
  });
  on('after:screenshot', (details) => {
     return nodeEvents.renameAndMoveScreenshot(details)
  })
}
```

`login.spec.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="cypress"/>
describe('screenshot test', () => {
    beforeEach(()=>{
        cy.visit('/')
    });

    it('Visits the hr test', () => {
        cy.task('sendSpecNameToPlugin', Cypress.spec.name)
        cy.screenshot('test')
    )}
})
```

`index.ts`:

```
export * from './lib/takess';
```

I wanted to save the screenshot filename in this directory:

Cypress

```
>dist\cypress\apps\hr
   >screenshtos
       >login.cy.ts
```

I am not able to get the spec name. so my screenshot is saved outside the login.cy.ts folder and I cant add the spec name into the screenshot filename

![image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cy.state()` to get the test title,

```js
cy.task('sendSpecNameToPlugin', cy.state('test').title)
```

but in the task if you want path to be `cypress/screenshots/testname/testname--timestamp.png` then adjust your code in `after:screenshot` hook like this

```js
const filename = `${testname}--${timeStamp} (failed).png`;
const path = `../../screenshots/${testname}`
const newPath = `${path}/${filename}`
```

If you have typescript error for `cy.state`, add a type definition

**cypress.d.ts**

```js
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface cy {
      state: any;          
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter'.ts(2339) i am getting this error when using the state. it seems that this method is not available on my side

Comment: It's just typescript error but code runs - adding a type definition calms the error.